# Posting Json Object and FormData( file) to controller with parameter MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I am tyring to create registration page. And i want users to upload image on registration. I created a action on controller with two parameters. One is model and other is HttpPostFileBase object. but i cant pass this two object at the same time. i tried a lot of approach but i cant figure it out. thanks.

On click register calling Register() metod.

```
function Register() {


    var team = { id: $("#team").val() }
    var account =
    {
        eMailAddress: $("#eMailAddress").val(),
        userName: $("#userName").val(),
        password: $("#password").val(),
        password2: $("#password2").val(),
        firstName: $("#firstName").val(),
        lastName: $("#lastName").val(),
        gender: $("#gender").val(),
        team: team,
        birthday: $("#birthday").val(),
        phoneAreaCode: $("#phoneAreaCode").val(),
        phoneLocalNumber: $("#phoneLocalNumber").val()
    }

    var imageFile = $('#image').get(0).files[0];


    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("image", imageFile);
    data.append('account', account);

    console.log(typeof data);

    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "/Registration/Register",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $("#message").hide();
            $("#message").empty();

            if (response.isSucceeded) {

                window.location.replace("/Login/Login");
            }
            else {

                $.each(response.errors, function (i, error) {
                    $("#message").append(error + "<br>");
                });
                $("#message").fadeIn();

            }


        }
    });
}
```

and there is Controller Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register( HttpPostedFileBase image,Account account )
        {

        account.team = serviceFactory.Run<GetTeamByIdResponse>(x => x.GetTeamById(new GetTeamByIdRequest(account.team.id))).team;
        account.GenerateVerificationCode();

        CreateAccountRequest request = new CreateAccountRequest();
        request.account = account;
        request.image = image;
        request.server = Server;
        CreateAccountResponse response = serviceFactory.Run<CreateAccountResponse>(x => x.CreateAccount(request));

        if (response.isSucceeded)
        {
            //toDo

        }
        return Json(response);
    }

<div class="kayit-ol-box">

            <ul>
                <li>
                    E-posta<br>

                    <input id="eMailAddress" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    Kullanıcı Adı<br>
                    <input id="userName" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    Şifre<br>
                    <input id="password" type="password">
                </li>
                <li>
                    Şifre Tekrar<br>
                    <input id="password2" type="password">
                </li>
                <li>
                    Ad<br>
                    <input id="firstName" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    Soyad<br>
                    <input id="lastName" type="text">
                </li>
                <li>
                    Cinsiyet<br>
                    <select id="gender">
                        <option value="Erkek">
                            Erkek
                        </option>
                        <option value="Kadın">
                            Kadın
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    Doğum Tarihi<br>
                    <input id="birthday" type="date" value="" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    Cep Telefonu<br>
                    <input class="alankodu" type="number" id="phoneAreaCode" />
                    <input class="telefon" id="phoneLocalNumber" type="number" step="1" min="10">
                </li>
                <li>
                    Tuttuğunuz Takım<br>
                    <select id="team">
                        <option selected value="0">
                            Tutmuyorum
                        </option>
                        @if (Model != null)
                        {
                            foreach (Team team in Model)
                            {
                                <option value="@team.id">
                                    @team.name
                                </option>
                            }
                        }
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    Avatar Ekle<br>
                    <span>Maximum 700 kb (jpg, png, gif)</span><br>
                    <input class="" id="image" name="image" type="file">

                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="izin" value="1" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked" />
                    <label for="checkbox21" id="izin" class="css-label">
                        Üyelik Sözleşmesi 'ni okudum ve kabul
                        ediyorum.
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <button class="kayit-submit" type="button" id="submit" onclick="Register()">ÜYELİĞİ TAMAMLA</button>

                </li>
```

i cant pass both of it. one of them always null

Comment: What is your server code language?

Comment: @Neal question updated.

Comment: what should i do. that's MVC project with c#

Comment: There is no tag for c# in your question...

Comment: okey sorry for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120975/discussion-between-ozan-erturk-and-neal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had created a fiddle couple of months back to try this out. Find the fiddle here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/qc4L8l

Try passing json object in formData in below format:

```
data.append(account["id"], value_of_id);
```